# How to implement Array.to_list and Array.of_list in OCaml

Tags: arrays, module, ocaml

I wonder implementation of to_list and of_list functions of an Array module.

Comment: OCaml is open-source so the best reference is its source code (which is, by the way, very readable, both the standard library implementation and the compiler),
https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/e5e9c5fed56efdd67601e4dbbaebeb134aee361c/stdlib/array.ml#L141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCaml `Stdlib` code is very readable, you can check it yourself in `stdlib/array.ml`.

Here they are, for reference:

```
let rec list_length accu = function
  | [] -> accu
  | _::t -> list_length (succ accu) t

let to_list a =
  let rec tolist i res =
     if i < 0 then res
     else tolist (i - 1) (unsafe_get a i :: res)
  in
  tolist (length a - 1) []

let of_list = function
    [] -> [||]
  | hd::tl as l ->
      let a = create (list_length 0 l) hd in
      let rec fill i = function
          [] -> a
        | hd::tl -> unsafe_set a i hd; fill (i+1) tl
      in
      fill 1 tl
```

Notes:

`unsafe_get`, `unsafe_set`, `length`, and `create` are defined externally (not in OCaml).

The `Array` module has its own version of `List.length` to avoid circular dependence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how these functions are implemented in the standard library, you're welcome to read the [source code](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/e5e9c5fed56efdd67601e4dbbaebeb134aee361c/stdlib/array.ml#L141) of the implementation as it is the best reference.

If you wonder how these functions could be implemented using the standard library functions (i.e., without relying on internal representation, known only to the implementors of the standard library), then here is a possible implementation of these functions,

```
let array_to_list xs =
  Array.fold_right List.cons xs []

let array_of_list xs = match xs with
  | [] -> [||]
  | default :: _ ->
    let arr = Array.make (List.length xs) default in
    List.iteri (Array.set arr) xs;
    arr
```